What happens when 2 parties enter into a MNDA while having independently developed the same intellectual property and 1 party discloses the IP to 2nd
Party A (A) and Party B (B) sign a MNDA (mutual non-disclosure agreement).  A and B MAY have independently developed identical IP.   Identical in this case means both instances of IP can be described as

Take information from sources X and Y
Use application Z to generate result Q by using info from X and Y.

X and Y are the same for each party and while likely containing confidential information belonging to a third party, the type of information and its format is publicly known.
Application Z is not a particular product but rather a common type of technology with one or more similar products using the same technique in a general sense.
A discloses its IP described above to B.
What can B do?
What if B publicly disclosed the IP prior to disclosure by A?
You might ask why A & B are working together when they are possibly competitors.
This question and answer discovered after original post are useful:
Is it possible for a party to a contract to use a mutual NDA primarily to constrain the other party?

But what would be the purpose of signing an MNDA if B plans to violate it?

Apologies for unclear question.  B speculates that IP IS IDENTICAL.  B would disclose before MNDA in place and before knowing of A’s IP.  No violation would be intended

Don't apologize, just clarify.

As mentioned in the answer to the previous question, an NDA usually excludes information that each party already had before entering the agreement. So if they each independently invented Z, it would not be included.

Normally an MNDA is to prevent the parties A and B from disclosing the information to a third party. This question seems to be asking about one party to an MNDA disclosing information to the other party to the MNDA. Is that really what is being asked?

In general, this question is written in a way that is very unclear and hard to follow.

I can imagine agreements that would allow B to disclose the information and agreements that would require B to not disclose the information. What B's rights and obligations are will depend on the particular agreement.
